# Adding regex to whitelist in firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

How do I input RegEx into the whitelist for Firebase Dynamic Links? As shown below, the input boxes only allow URLs. I am on the dynamic link page for firebase console as the documentation [suggests](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429?authuser=0&hl=en).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click the "Save" button on this window, then click the 'Allow list URL pattern' button. Then you can edit RegEx patterns.